# React Material-UI checkbox onChange event does not fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Trying to use Material UI checkbox. Pretty simple one might think? Well the checkbox doesn't toggle. Turns out the onChange event is not fired even internally to the component (I put logs in the node_modules package).

```
      <Checkbox
        checked={this.state.isTrue}
        onChange={e => {
          console.log(e.target.checked);
          this.setState({isTrue: e.target.checked});
        }} />
```

Pretty simple, right? But the `console.log` never fires. I can hack around it by putting an `onClick` event handler on the component and toggling the state manually, but that is silly. Anyone have a clue?

The API is at https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#checkbox. Not rocket science.

Comment: Not sure about your code but check out https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-saha-0ytjr and as a trick, as possible as you can prefer use function/hooks instead class components :)

Comment: The code looks fine, you can check more here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ock3u?fontsize=14

Comment: very old topic, but I would suggest you use callback for `setState()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue might come from the structure of your component as provided code is perfectly fine, here is a working exemple you can try on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-ywrhs?fontsize=14).

Compare with your code and try to find differences, but isolating a specific element might be a good way to realise **the issue might come from somewhere else**.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Checkbox from "material-ui/Checkbox";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isTrue: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Checkbox
          checked={this.state.isTrue}
          onChange={e => {
            console.log(e.target.checked);
            this.setState({ isTrue: e.target.checked });
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Yeah. So as it happens I am operating in an environment where there is a stylesheet over which I have no control, which tends to get its filthy fingers into everything. Once I removed all its nastiness, the checkbox works again.

Answer (score 16):

In many cases, Material UI Checkbox **onChange** event is not working.

I suggest to save your time and use **onClick** event instead.

It will work always. Checkbox usually have a boolean value.

```
 <Checkbox
    checked={this.state.isTrue}
    onClick={() => this.setState({isTrue: !this.state.isTrue})}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, maybe something else is wrong somewhere. However, for a quick POC, you can refer to this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ock3u?fontsize=14).
This is the same forked from material UI official docs demo so you could relate easily.

Additionally, you can compare the code with given below

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

export default function Checkboxes() {
  const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = React.useState(false);


  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        checked={isTrue}
        onChange={e=> {
          console.log("target checked? - ", e.target.checked);
          setIsTrue(e.target.checked)
        }}
        value="checkedA"
        inputProps={{
          'aria-label': 'primary checkbox',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here are screenshots for verification
[image]
[image]

References: https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/

Answer (score 0):

In the Material UI (in version `5.0.0-beta.4`) the `onChange` event is called when the `input[type= "checkbox"]` is clicked (this element is transparent, but clicking on it is important). Perhaps the problem is that your styles change `input[type= "checkbox"]`.

P.S. I had a problem with the styles `input[type= "checkbox"] { width: 0; height: 0;}` were prioritized and the mouse click clicked on the usual element, and not on `input[type= "checkbox"]`.

P.P.S. Look at the styles through the developer tools for working options from the documentation and for your own version, you will find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the above does not work for you, check your css, especially if you have global CSS. Chrome dev tools (Elements section) will help here. Look for **tags**, **classes**, and especially **elements** in the CSS. A few pointers below:

```
label {
css1: value1,
}

&.checked {
css1: value1,
}

&.disabled {
css1: value1
}
```

If you find any of this, they could easily override the mui css.

Answer (score -1):

I just had this trouble, for the checkbox onChange you have to check on the "checked" (event.target.checked) variable, not the "value"

[image: code sample]